# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, subprocess

I got an error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined` on line 36 of my file `index.js` (see script below). I'm calling it from a Python subprocess

**Note:** I must call index.js through a subprocess

For some odd reason, the program works 20% of the time, other than that I keep getting this error. How do I fix this error?

**main.py**

```
import os
import subprocess

filePath = "/file/path/index.js"

command = subprocess.Popen(["node", filePath, "https://video.com/link"])
stdout, stderr = command.communicate()
command.wait()
```

**Error**

```
(node:64821) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at /full/path/index.js:36:23
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:64821) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:64821) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**index.js**

```
const urlRegex = require("url-regex");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require("https");

if (process.argv.length <= 2) {
  console.log('Missing URL.');
  console.log('Usage: node index.js <url>');
  process.exit(0);
}

let url = process.argv[2];

if (url.endsWith('/')) url = url.substring(0, url.length - 1);

const urlParts = url.split("/");
let id = urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];

if (id.includes("?")) id = id.split("?")[0];

console.log(`URL > ${url}`);
console.log(`ID > ${id}`);

fetch(url)
  .then(res => {
    return res.text();
  })
  .then(body => {
    const urls = body.match(urlRegex());
    const baseUrl = urls.find(url => url.includes("playlist.m3u8"))

    let liveUrl = baseUrl;
    
    liveUrl = liveUrl.replace("pull-hls", "pull-flv");
    liveUrl = liveUrl.split("/").slice(0, 5).join("/")
    liveUrl += ".flv"

    console.log(`Found live playlist (m3u8) URL: ${baseUrl}`);
    console.log(`Found live flv URL: ${liveUrl}`);

    console.log(`Writing live to output.flv. Press Ctrl C to STOP.`)
    
    const file = fs.createWriteStream('output_path/output.flv')
    https.get(liveUrl, function (response) {
      response.pipe(file);
    });

    fs.writeFile('output_path/completion_check.txt', 'Hello World!', function (err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log('completion_check.txt has been created');
    });

  });
```

Comment: The error means that `liveUrl` is undefined, which means that searching `urls` for the playlist string didn't return a match.

Comment: @ChrisG How can I fix that?

Comment: Something like wrapping the part of the code that relies on the playlist string being found in `if (liveUrl) {` and `} else console.log("playlist not found");` should do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that on your line 32, the `.find` function can return `undefined` and you cannot call any methods (`.replace` in this case) on an `undefined` value:

```
const baseUrl = urls.find(url => url.includes("playlist.m3u8"))
```

Add a check after this line before proceeding. For example:

```
if (baseUrl === undefined) {
   console.log("Did not find any matching URLs")
   return;
}
```

More on how `.find` works:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: I later realized the problem wasn't part of the script, the check didn't solve my problem but it made the console easier to work with so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As the terminal shows try to launch the node script adding **--trace-warnings** to show where the warning was created.

You should try:

```
command = subprocess.Popen(["node --trace-warnings", filePath, "https://video.com/link"])
```

Then you should also add a catch block inside your promise, you can see the message in your terminal (This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()). Whit this is easy to see where is originated the error.

```
fetch(url)
.then(res => {
    return res.text();
})
.then(body => {
    const urls = body.match(urlRegex());
    const baseUrl = urls.find(url => url.includes("playlist.m3u8"))

    let liveUrl = baseUrl;

    liveUrl = liveUrl.replace("pull-hls", "pull-flv");
    liveUrl = liveUrl.split("/").slice(0, 5).join("/")
    liveUrl += ".flv"

    console.log(`Found live playlist (m3u8) URL: ${baseUrl}`);
    console.log(`Found live flv URL: ${liveUrl}`);

    console.log(`Writing live to output.flv. Press Ctrl C to STOP.`)

    const file = fs.createWriteStream('output_path/output.flv')
    https.get(liveUrl, function (response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    });

    fs.writeFile('output_path/completion_check.txt', 'Hello World!', function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('completion_check.txt has been created');
    });
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: It's only an unhandled promise rejection because this very basic null pointer error happened to happen inside a promise :/ not sure this answer will help OP, as opposed to confuse them?

Comment: I see it's a null pointer exception, but with a correct message on terminal he can understand well where's the problem. It's a good practice.

Comment: But the error OP has posted already says `Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`? What will they gain by adding obscure flags to their process command? The problem is a very common newbie problem and it's about understanding what the error message is referring to by `undefined`, not promises and error stacks.

Comment: These two recommendations are sound advice as troubleshooting tools for this and future problems that involve promises, which are part of the title and description of the question. Part of the OP "How do I fix this error?" answer can certainly include these suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

A tricky thing about `String.prototype.match` is that unless the `RegExp` has the `g` (global) flag, you will not match multiple values. It looks like you're using the [`url-regex`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-regex) package, which does not return a RegExp with the `g` flag set, so you're not going to be getting the array of matches like you expect. So that might be why finding the URL you expect is turning up `undefined`.

You'll have to convert that URL to a global, something like this:

```
const allUrls = new RegExp(urlRegex().source, 'ig'); // Case insensitive, global

// ...

const urls = body.match(allUrls);
const baseUrl = urls.find((url => url.includes("playlist.m3u8"));
```

Of course, you'll also want to check that `baseUrl` was found:

```
if (!baseUrl) {
  // Or however you want to handle this case...
  throw new Error('Base URL containing playlist.m3u8 was not found');
}
```

Comment: I placed `const allUrls = new RegExp(urlRegex().source, 'ig');` but the console returned `(node:71971) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: allUrls is not a function` when I replaced `urlRegex` with `allUrls` on `const urls = body.match(allUrls);`

Comment: Did you accidentally do `body.match(allUrls())` instead of `body.match(allUrls)`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the library [url-regex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-regex), but reading [this source file](https://github.com/kevva/url-regex/blob/master/index.js) seem that the default option for the `strict` parameter is `true`. You can try to print out the partial results with the console api, es `console.log(body, body.match(urlRegex()))` or using [the debugger api of node](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) (or you can use vscode that has a very nice debugger for JavaScript)

Also maybe, in urls, there is no url that includes the "playlist.m3u8" string, so `urls.find(url => url.includes("playlist.m3u8"))` returns `undefined`. You can chain a `.catch(error => { ... })` to the *fetch()* call, after the `.then(body => { ... })` in order to handle exceptions